# How to extract and print values in list with %in% function (in order) on R

Tags: r

I have a very unique problem that I'd hope would have a solution.

```
data <- data.frame('col1' = c('hi', 'hey', 'bye', 'cya'))
```

The data above is simply a column with greeting and leaving values

I have two vectors here.

```
greet <- c('hey', 'hi')
leave <- c('cya', 'bye')
```

I've put them in the opposite order as I want to match the order as it shows in the table. Now I apply the function

```
guesslabel <- function(table, m) {
  data %>% dplyr::mutate(guess = ifelse(col1 %in%(m), m, 'none'))
}
```

When I run the function as such

```
guesslabel(data, greet)
```

I get the following output:

> col1:     _____      guess:
>
> hey      _____       hi
>
> hi       _____       hey
>
> bye      _____       none
>
> cya       _____      none

The output that I want:

> col1:     _____      guess:
>
> hey      _____       hey
>
> hi       _____       hi
>
> bye      _____       none
>
> cya       _____      none

Sorry about the formatting, unsure how to do that. I was just wondering how I'd extract the specific value from the list greet that is being used to filter the column variable. So essentially, the column guess should match with col1 (Ignore the none values as that can be solved later), and I don't want to simply use the value from col1. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want `filter` ? `data %>% filter(col1 %in% greet)`

Comment: Not exactly, I'd like to add an additional column that gets the value from the greet list. It's a weird request but it's a specific design feature for the data that I'm using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use `match` -

```
library(dplyr)

guesslabel <- function(table, m) {
  table %>% 
    mutate(guess = m[match(col1, m)], 
           guess = tidyr::replace_na(guess, 'none'))
}

guesslabel(data, greet)

#  col1 guess
#1   hi    hi
#2  hey   hey
#3  bye  none
#4  cya  none

guesslabel(data, leave)

#  col1 guess
#1   hi  none
#2  hey  none
#3  bye   bye
#4  cya   cya
```